# swift multiple conditions if statement with && operation

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

I have 4 text boxes.I don't want to allow user to let all these 4 textfields empty. How can I check multiple conditions in swift. I did like this but it's giving me an error

```
 if self.txtIncomeAd.text?.isEmpty && self.txtIncomeRec.text?.isEmpty &&
```

like wise. What is the correct way I can do this?
Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can simply use  isEmpty  property.

```
if !self.textFieldOne.text!.isEmpty && !self.textFieldTwo.text!.isEmpty && !self.textFieldThree.text!.isEmpty && !self.textFieldFour.text!.isEmpty {
 ...

}
```

or you can also safely unwrap the text value and the check that it is empty of not

```
if let text1 = self.textFieldOne.text, text2 = self.textFieldTwo.text, text3 = self.textFieldthree.text,text4 = self.textFieldFour.text where !text1.isEmpty && !text2.isEmpty && !text3.isEmpty && !text4.isEmpty {
  ...
  }
```

Or you can compare with Empty "" String

```
if self.textFieldOne.text != "" && self.textFieldTwo.text != "" && self.textFieldThree.text != "" && self.textFieldFour.text != ""   {
  ...
}
```

and we can also do this with `Guard`

```
guard let text = self.myTextField.text  where !text.isEmpty else {
  return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if !self.txtIncomeAd.text!.isEmpty && !self.txtIncomeRec.text!.isEmpty && !self.txtIncomeAd.text!.isEmpty && !self.txtIncomeRec.text!.isEmpty
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It gives you an error because the text in the textField is optional. First you have to unwrap them all.

```
if let txtIncomeAd = self.txtIncomeAd.text,
     let txtIncomeRec = self.txtIncomeRec.text {
            if txtIncomeAd.isEmpty && txtIncomeRec.isEmpty {
                 // Do Something
            }
} else {
    // Empty text field
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with **isEmpty** boolean property.

```
 if ((inputTextField.text?.isEmpty) != nil && (inputTextField1.text?.isEmpty)!= nil && (inputTextField2.text?.isEmpty)!=nil) {

    }
```

or

```
  if ((inputTextField.text?.isEmpty)! && (inputTextField1.text?.isEmpty)! && (inputTextField2.text?.isEmpty)!) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something a bit different:

```
extension UILabel {
    var textIsEmpty: Bool { return text?.isEmpty ?? true }
}

class MyClass: UIView {
    let txtIncomeAd = UILabel()
    let txtIncomeRec = UILabel()

    var textFieldsAreNonEmpty: Bool {
        return ![txtIncomeAd, txtIncomeRec].contains { $0.textIsEmpty }
    }
}

let c = MyClass()

c.txtIncomeAd.text = "hello"
c.txtIncomeRec.text = "there"

if c.textFieldsAreNonEmpty {
    print("text fields are valid")
}
```